# R, Create K-nearest neighbors weights in a Matrix

Tags: r, knn

I have a 2-column data frame corresponding to **X** and **Y** cartesian coordinates of a sample of 500 georeferenced observations.
I want to generate a weight Matrix **W** where each elements is equal to:
* **1**    :**if** observation ***j*** is one of the **k-nearest neighbors** to observation ***i***, and
* **0**    :**if else**.
Suppose we have this data frame:

```
    df=as.data.frame(cbind(x=rnorm(500), y=rnorm(500)))
```

And let suppose **k= 20**, so how to create this matrix with R ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CRAN's `FastKNN` package... Let's say you have your distance matrix of `5 * 5` as follows:

```
library(FastKNN)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x = rnorm(5), y=rnorm(5)))
dist_mat <- as.matrix(dist(df, method = "euclidean", upper = TRUE, diag=TRUE))

## Let's say k = 2...
k <- 2
nrst <- lapply(1:nrow(dist_mat), function(i) k.nearest.neighbors(i, dist_mat, k = k))

## Build w
w <- matrix(nrow = dim(dist_mat), ncol=dim(dist_mat)) ## all NA right now
w[is.na(w)] <- 0 ## populate with 0
for(i in 1:length(nrst)) for(j in nrst[[i]]) w[i,j] = 1
```

So my `df` looked like this:

```
> df
           x            y
1 -0.2109351 -0.315256132
2  0.5172415  0.003352551
3  1.5700413 -0.737475081
4 -0.2699282 -0.198414683
5  1.3997493 -0.241382737
```

And my `w` ended up looking like this:

```
> w
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    0    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0    1
[4,]    1    1    0    0    0
[5,]    0    1    1    0    0
```

Comment: I tried the code on my big data frame and it works GREAT !! Thanks